# PHP - Could you use POST method to stream data to a server over a long period of time?

Tags: php, html, cgi, http-post

Caveat, I know this has the potential to be a ridiculously stupid question, but I had the thought and want to know the answer.

Aim: run an interactive session between browser and server with a single request without ajax or websockets etc..

Scenario: a PHP file on the server receives data by POST method from a user. The content length in the header is 8MB so it keeps the connection open until it receives the full data of 8MB. But on the user side we are delivering this data very very slowly (simulating a terrible connection, for example). The server is receiving the data bits at a time. [can this be passed to the PHP file to process bits at a time? Or does it only get passed once all the data is received?] It then does whatever it wants with those bits, and delivers it to the browser, in an echo loop). At certain time intervals, the user injects new data into the 'stream' which will be surrounded by a continuous stream of padding data.

Is any of that possible? Or even with CGI? I am expecting this not to be possible really, but what stops the process timing out if someone does have a terrible connection and the POST data is huge?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you could do this, but the PHP file you are calling with the POST data will only be called by the webserver once it has received all the data. Otherwise, say you were sending an image with POST, and your PHP script moves this image from the tempfiles directory to another directory, before all the data has been received, you would have a corrupt image, nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the ini configurations have been altered correctly, I would think so. But would be a great test to try out!

Comment: What ini settings could you change to stream the data rather than wait until the block is received?